# Convert a map to json but still show the correct schema in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I Have a map of `Map[String, Seq[Map[String,String]]`
I converted the map to json string and The problem is when I print the schema of my df. I always see StringType. I want to see the correct schema of the Json.
for example I have

```scala
val myMap =  Map("diff" -> Seq(Map("first_name" -> "John", "last_name" -> "Bo"),Map("first_name" -> "Kevin", "last_name" -> "Po")))
```

what I tried is:

```scala
val df = (myMap)
 .toDF("data")
 .withColumn("data", to_json(struct(col("data"))))
```

the actual result of df.schema

```
 |-- diff_data: string (nullable = true)
```

but I expect to get:

```
|-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- diff: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- last_name: string (nullable = true)
```

and still see the result as json string format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the that `to_json` function returns a String column, so this is expected behaviour.

If you want to extract a structured column out of that string, you can use the `from_json` function by supplying it with a schema. Let's make a reproducible case:

```scala
import spark.implicits._
val myMap =  Map("diff" -> Seq(
  Map("first_name" -> "John", "last_name" -> "Bo"),
  Map("first_name" -> "Kevin", "last_name" -> "Po")
))

val df = Seq(myMap).
  toDF("data").
  withColumn("data", to_json(col("data")))

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- data: string (nullable = true)
```

We see we indeed get the single string column. If we now define the wanted schema and use the from_json function, we can get the schema we want:

```scala
val elementSchema = new StructType().
  add($"first_name".string).
  add($"last_name".string)
val schema = new StructType().
  add($"diff".array(elementSchema))

val parsedDf = df.withColumn("data", from_json(col("data"), schema))

scala> parsedDf.printSchema()
root
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- diff: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- last_name: string (nullable = true)

scala> parsedDf.show(false)
+---------------------------+
|data                       |
+---------------------------+
|{[{John, Bo}, {Kevin, Po}]}|
+---------------------------+
```

Comment: There is no option to see the "data" as json in the table? in your example i see only the values I am looking to see the keys either

Comment: It seems like you might be confused about json in Spark. If you want your data to be printed out in json notation, you will need a StringType column for that. But then you don't have the benefit of having a schema. With a schema (like I showed here), the underlying structure is there. When you execute `df.show` you don't see the whole json notation, but the keys are totally there! `df.show` is not really used in production scenarios either, so it's not that important. I hope this helps clearing out some of your questions! :)

Answer (score 0):

to_json returns a json string, so it's type is StringType.

If you want to keep the original perhaps use:

```scala
val df = (myMap)
    .toDF("data")
    .select("data", to_json(struct(col("data"))).as("json_data"))
```

Also note, although not an issue in your example, json/to_json cannot handle maps with keys that are not strings, Quality added [to_yaml](https://sparkutils.github.io/quality/0.1.1/sqlfunctions/#to_yaml)/from_yaml for that reason.

Comment: in your example I am still get json_data as string

Comment: as I wrote that can't change, a string has type StringType.